# Remove everything from text except what is in brackets with Regex

Tags: notepad++, regex

I would like to use notepad++ to remove everything in a text file except anything found between [ ].

Example:

```
[D-1.1.1-A] - bla bla text here[D-1.1.1-B] - some more bla bla text here[D-1.1.1-C] - even more bla bla
```

would become:

```
[D-1.1.1-A][D-1.1.1-B][D-1.1.1-C]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you're asking for can be more complicated than a regex if the input is more complex.
However if the input is always as written, then

```
Ctrl-H
Find what: [^\]]+(\[|$)
Replace with: \1
```

should do it

Comment: yes, but this regex will delete also all the lines before the specific line with brackets :(

Answer (score 3):

You can look for `[^\[]*(\[.*?\])[^\[]*`
(make sure "search mode" is "regular expression" and maybe check "wrap around")

And replace it to `$1`

An [example](https://regex101.com/r/nF7hC8/1).

Comment: How are $1 and /1 different?

Answer (score 2):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\[.*?\](*SKIP)(*FAIL)|.+?`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
  \[.*?\]       # 1 or more any charact, not greedy, between opening and closing square brackets
  (*SKIP)       # Special verb, forget it
  (*FAIL)       # Special verb, assume there is no match
|             # OR
  .+?           # 1 or more any character, not greedy
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]